# clearInterval() not clearing setInterval()

Tags: javascript, intervals, clearinterval

**What is wrong with this code?**

The interval will not clear, I've tried everything I can think of.

I've searched through other questions and cannot find an answer, there are similar problems, but the solutions don't work here!

```
var opacity = 1;
var opac = opacity * 100;
var fadeInterval;
var fadeTiming = fade_timing / 100;
function fadeOut() { console.log("fadeOut called!");
    opac = opac - 1;
    opacity = opac / 100; console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if(opac < 0) {setInterval(fadeIn, fadeInterval)};
};
function fadeIn() { console.log("fadeIn called!");
    opac = opac + 1;
    opacity = opac / 100; console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if(opac > 100) {clearInterval(fadeInterval); console.log("clearInterval")};
};

function fade() { console.log("fade called!");
    fadeInterval = setInterval(fadeOut, fadeTiming);
};
```

Comment: The issue seems in this line `if(opac < 0) {setInterval(fadeIn, fadeInterval)};` , you need to pass `fadeTiming` instead of `fadeInterval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem seems to be in function `fadeOut()`, at this line:

```
if(opac < 0) {setInterval(fadeIn, fadeInterval)}; //<-- required fadeTiming instead, also missing the assignment
```

Try this:

```
if(opac < 0) {
  clearInterval(fadeInterval); //make sure if the interval isn't already running
  fadeInterval = setInterval(fadeIn, fadeTiming);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var opacity = 1;
var opac = opacity * 100;
var fadeInterval;
var fadeTiming = fade_timing / 100;
function fadeOut() { console.log("fadeOut called!");
    opac = opac - 1;
    opacity = opac / 100; console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity + ". opac: " + opac);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if(opac < 0) { clearInterval(fadeInterval);fadeInterval=setInterval(fadeIn, fadeInterval)};
};
function fadeIn() { console.log("fadeIn called!");
    opac = opac + 1;
    opacity = opac / 100; console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if(opac > 100) {clearInterval(fadeInterval); console.log("clearInterval")};
};

function fade() { console.log("fade called!");
    fadeInterval = setInterval(fadeOut, fadeTiming);
};
```

Clear fadeInterval in fadeOut  before setting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the first interval in `fadeOut()`

```
var opacity = 1;
var opac = opacity * 100;
var fadeInterval;
var fadeTiming = fade_timing / 100;

function fadeOut() {
    console.log("fadeOut called!");
    opac = opac - 1;
    opacity = opac / 100;
    console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if (opac < 0) {
        //clear the interval from fade here
        clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        //store the new interval reference in fadeInterval
        fadeInterval = setInterval(fadeIn, fadeInterval)
    };
};

function fadeIn() {
    console.log("fadeIn called!");
    opac = opac + 1;
    opacity = opac / 100;
    console.log("fading... opacity: " + opacity);
    image.style.opacity = opacity;
    if (opac > 100) {
        //clear the interval created in fadeOut
        clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        console.log("clearInterval")
    };
};

function fade() {
    console.log("fade called!");
    fadeInterval = setInterval(fadeOut, fadeTiming);
};
```